# How to return 2 leading 0 in toString() method?

Tags: java, date, oop

```java
public class Date 
{

   private int day,
               month,
               year;

   public Date(int day, int month, int year)
   {
      this.day=day;
      this.month=month;  
      this.year=year;   
   }

   public int getday()
   {  
       return day;    
   }

   public int getmon()
   {
       return month;  
   }

   public int getyear()
   {
         return year;   
   }

   public void setd(int day)
   {

      this.day=day;
   }

   public void setm(int month)
   {

      this.month=month;
   }

   public void sety(int year)
   {

      this.year=year;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return " "+getday()+"/"+getmon()+"/"+getyear();
   }
}
```

How to make the `toString` method to return 2 leading 0? So that if I call it in the main if I call the `toString` method it will print

The **output** of that is 
**2**/10/199

my expected **output**

**02**/10/1999

Comment: As an aside, if you're writing a `Date` class as an exercise, that's a fine exercise. For production code one would never do it but would use the built-in `LocalDate` class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn to search before asking a new question. Chances are that your question has been asked before and that you will find a wealth of good answers without having to wait for someone to write a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your function with String.format()

```
public String toString()
   {
      return " "+String.format("%02d", getday())+"/"+getmon()+"/"+getyear();
   }
```

Sample output

```
getDay(); //prints "1"
String.format("%02d", getday()); //prints "01"
```

Comment: this check button in the left side?

Comment: yes that @sireee

Comment: Your can also do this 
```NumberFormat strFormat = new DecimalFormat("00");  
strFormat.format(22); //prints "22"
strFormat.format(21); // prints "01"```

Comment: I would go all in: `String.format("%02d/%02d/%d", getday(), getmon(), getyear())`.